# Is there a way to collapse values in a dataframe column based on parameters of values in the same column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of dates and values. ie

```
    index |   date   | points 
      0   |  9-15-17 |  10.2
      1   |  9-15-17 |  5.0
      2   |  9-15-17 |  -3.0
      3   |  9-15-17 |  -1.6
      4   |  9-15-17 |  3.8
      5   |  9-15-17 |  7.0
      6   |  9-15-17 |  4.6
```

Is there a way to utilize groupby in pandas to collapse the dataframe into

```
   index |   date   | points
     0   |  9-15-17 |  15.2
     1   |  9-15-17 |  -4.6
     2   |  9-15-17 |  15.4
```

I'm currently sending date column, and points to lists and using multiple loops to check the values (Dataframe is C_list)

```
net_score = 0
rolling_score = []


print(type(int(C_list[0])))

for i in range(0,len(C_list)):
    if C_list[i] > 0:
        if(net_score + C_list[i] > net_score):
        net_score += C_list[i]
    else:
            rolling_score.append(net_score)
            net_score = 0
            net_score += C_list[i]
    if C_list[i] < 0:
        if(net_score + C_list[i] < net_score):
            net_score += C_list[i]

    else:
                rolling_inv.append(net_inv)
                net_inv = 0
                net_inv += C_list[i]
```

For some reason I get a list back as such : [15.2,-3.0], so it stops adding values when I get to negative points for some reason. I'm realizing there may be an easier way to do this within the dataframe, but I am having a hard time understanding how to properly utilize pandas to do so. Not so much looking for full code, but I'm looking for some insight as to whether this is even possible to do easily in the dataframe, and what the suggested functions to use are.

Comment: Maybe an idea could be to add another index that is the same for various group, then apply groupby to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
m=df['points'].lt(0).ne(df['points'].lt(0).shift()).cumsum()
df1= df.groupby([m,'date']).sum().drop(columns=['index'])
df1.index = df1.index.droplevel(0)
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(df1)
```

**output**

```
       date     points
0   9-15-17     15.2
1   9-15-17     -4.6
2   9-15-17     15.4
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! the 'lt' and 'ne' functions were something I was totally unfamiliar with

Comment: Glad to be of help. Consider up-voting & accepting the answer.